# Get value of button in a popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a button which has current date value. When I click on the button a popup form should get opened and it will have a text box which will contain the value from the button. And after submitting the form, the button value should get changed accordingly

this is my HTML form

```
 <button id="appDate" ></button>
<div id="popupForm" style="display:none;">
    <form action = "" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name = "date" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  now = new Date();
  y = now.getFullYear();
  m = now.getMonth()+1;
  d = now.getDate();
  h = now.getHours();
  mi = now.getMinutes();
  full_date = y + '-' + (m<10?'0'+m:m) + '-' + (d<10?'0'+d:d) + ' ' + (h<10?'0'+h:h) + ':' +(mi<10?'0'+mi:mi);
  $('#appDate').text(full_date);
});

  $(function(){
    $( "#popupForm" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#appDate").click(function() {
    $("#popupForm").dialog('open');
  });
});
```

When I open the form I should be able to get that date in form and after submitting it, whatever I type in as date should be on Button

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @thst , I want to set text of button to input when the popup form opens. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook into change event of that input and set the button text accordingly:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
    $("#appDate").prop('value', $( this ).text());
});
```

To do something when the dialog is opened you have to pass a function to it's open field. At the end your code looks like this:

```
 $('#dialogbox').dialog({          
      autoOpen:false,
      open: function() {
          // use above code
      }
  });
```

Comment: `$( this ).text()` should be: `$( this ).val()`. Or, even better: `$("#appDate").val($( this ).val());`

Comment: @ScottMarcus How to set button text in that input when the popup loads?